# d3 - appending an id to path attribute

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I have a topojson file that has a `districts` object containing us districts. Each has an id property.
(Districts are in the orange)

I am simply trying to associate each districts id with the path, but I am not quite sure if there is a d3 specific way to handle that.

The problem I am facing is this is just appending the first id to all of the elements, not each id, which makes sense since im not looping over each object.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

```
  d3.json('js/fullus.json?v=3', function(error, us) {
    if (error) throw error;

    // districts  
    var districttracts = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.districts);
    svg.selectAll("path").data(districttracts.features.filter(function(d) {
        needle = d.id,
          index = contains.call(districtArray, needle); // true   
        return d
      }))
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "district-boundary")
      .attr("data-districtId", needle)
      .attr("d", path)
  });
```

[image]

Comment: D3 provides inline functions that make this easy. They are of the form `function (d,i){...}` where `d` and `i` (any variables) represent "data" (bound to the object) and "index" (number of the object in the selection). You can also simply do `function(){...}` if you don't need the parameters. So, it would simply be `.attr("data-districtId", function(d){return d.id;})`

Comment: @JSBob thank you very much, that worked. Had a feeling there was a d3 function that handled this case